# Return unique results (i.e. no duplicates) from a regex query

Tags: regex

How can I prevent this regex query `(?<=NASDAQ:).*` from showing duplicate results?

If it matches a result, for example "NEGG", I would like to highlight it just the one time.

I've set up an example here at regex101.com
[Example of regex](https://regex101.com/r/DWc9cA/1)

Would appreciate if anyone could help me with this.

Thanks.

Comment: You can't do this in the regexp itself. Remove the duplicates in the code that processes the results.

Comment: Hi, thank you but that only returns 2 results when there should be a lot more than that

Comment: So, what is the expected result, and why? I see you have just alphanumerics following `NASDAQ:` string, is that all you need to match after it? Then try `NASDAQ:(\w+)\b(?![\s\S]*NASDAQ:\1\b)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the regex engine used is either JS (new one )  or C#.
Both of which would allow you to use a well placed, variable length look behind.
This will allow to highlight only the first unique NASDAQ codes.

```
(?<=NASDAQ:)(?=(\w+))(?<!^[\s\S]*NASDAQ:\1[\s\S]*)\1
```

https://regex101.com/r/EeGy3E/1

```
 (?<= NASDAQ: )
 (?=
    ( \w+ )                       # (1)
 )
 (?<! ^ [\s\S]* NASDAQ: \1 [\s\S]* )
 \1
```